# Adding clickable gameobject c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm dynamically adding images to a scrollview from a json file/ url

I like to make the images clickable gameobject, but have no idea how to do this in c# ( void OnMouseDown() ???)

```
IEnumerator AddFeedItem (int index)
{
WWW www = new WWW (ModelURL); // img url
yield return www;

GameObject newsimageObject = tempFeedItem.transform.FindChild ("newsimage").gameObject;
Image newsImage = newsimageObject.GetComponent<Image> ();
Texture2D tempTex = photos [index % 10];

SpriteRenderer renderer = newsImage.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, 455, 230),new Vector2(0, 0),100.0f);

newsImage.sprite = sprite;
}
```

Comment: There are two ways. First you can use `Image` and put every object on UI. Second you can create objects witch `SpriteRenderer`. In first case you can use `ScrollView` that is included in Unity UI and use events to handle input.

Comment: Kevin dude, WTF?  just use the UI system built-in to Unity.  What you're doing is madness!  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an `Image`/`Canvas`. You should avoid `Raycast` and `OnMouseDown`. To detect touch with Image/Canvas, you use have to derive from `IPointerDownHandler` or `IPointerClickHandler` then implement the functions from them. `OnMouseDown` or `Raycast` should be used **only** if the Object is a **3D** model or if the Object is a `Sprite` that is **NOT** under a `Canvas`. In that case, a collider is required. In this case, you are using the `Image` component, so I assume this is under `Canvas`.

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerClickHandler
{
   public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      Debug.Log("Clicked");
   }

   public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      Debug.Log("Down");
   }

}
```

Comment: Hey, any reason why they should be avoided? Just curious, because I know Raycasts are pretty efficient and can be called many times - is it just the interface way is easier to use?

Comment: this is correct but im getting `Assets/scripts/clickTest.cs(5,60): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IPointerClickHandler' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
`

Comment: @ryrich They should be avoided because you are using Image/Canvas. The UI event is meant for that. You will have to attach collider to your Image for Raycast and OnMouseDown to work on an Image component. That is not how to use the Image Component. You should never attach a collider to an Image compoent. Waste of time and resources.

Comment: @kevinver Add `using UnityEngine.UI;` and `UnityEngine.EventSystems;` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a BoxCollider2D object atached to that GameObject and then Use

Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.position), Vector2.zero);

to test if there are any Collider in the Mouse.position.

Comment: oky i added the BoxCollider2D  http://i.imgur.com/DAeYjpp.png now where does the `Physics2D.Raycast(Cam....` go?

Comment: I always write it in Update().

The raycast returns a RaycastHit2D only if there are any collider in the target point)... otherwise it returns false.

if(HitInfo)
{
}